# Freeradius Server on debian 11 daloradius (mysql) wrong NAS-IP-Address

Tags: freeradius

searching for hours now and maybe i am searching wrong. Dont Know.

here is my Problem:
i set-up an freeradius on debian11 with mysql and daloradius.
So far its working fine  and i have two dirfferent Wlan-APs in use one is an Devolo Pro1750c and the other are Zyxel nwa1123.

The Devolo sends it NAS-IP-Address correct in the debug output of freradius.
The Zyxel sends always NAS-IP-Address = 127.0.0.1

May you give me a hint what to check or where to look? I dont have any ideas anymore ;-)
Thanks Jens

Comment: while further investigation. I found MAC-Addresses in the debug log which are not known in my Network

Comment: further investigation on the Wlan AP brings up that there is an extra configuration where i can set the NAS IP/ Identifier. Problem solved